# when i changed the IIS application pool's and sharepoint services's Service Account i start receving the following error "403 FORBIDDEN"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security, iis, application-pool

For security reasons we wanted to chnage the service accounts username for all the IIS application pools and SharePoint service , so we created a new user named "Staging.user", and i define it as a managed account inside SharePoint. and then we chnage the iis application pool and the SharePoint services to use this account, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

but after that some site collections will raise an 403 Forbidden error when trying to access them, while other will work. For example we have a list where all the views will work but the create form will raise 403 HTTP error , so we can edit the list items and delete them, but if we click on create form we will get 403 forbidden error.. so can anyone adivce what is causing this ?
Thanks

Comment: did you change the app pool account and services account from Central admin? did you peform IIS reset on servers? also did you clear the config cache

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE what do u mean by changing the app pool account on central admin ? and yes i restart the server and cleared the cach

Comment: From central admin > Security > Configure Service Accounts

Comment: aha ok i will update them now,, but meanwhile why  some site collections are working well, while other will return 403 ?  is there a reason behind this ?

Comment: how many WFE in the farm?

Comment: only one server

Comment: any clue in ULS logs when you get the 403 error...on which page it is getting?

Comment: for example i have enterprise wiki site collection, the 403 error will be on the welcome page or any other wiki pages.. while i have a team site where all its lists are working well, but i have an issue tracking list where 403 error will be shown only when users will try to create new issue, while edit/delete/view issus is woring well..

Comment: any clue in the ULS logs?

Comment: now after updating "central admin > Security > Configure Service Accounts" it is working well thanks a lot for your help. but if i try to access the site using IE i will keep entering my username and password , without being able to login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17970/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-john-g).

Comment: Looks like you 1st problem solved, i am entering that as anwser so that other & me get some credit.

Comment: ok thanks a lot i have opned another question regarding my new problem. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118508/my-site-collection-is-not-accessible-using-ie-chrome-while-i-can-access-it-u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you change the AppPool from IIS. It is highly recommended to update / Change the app Pool Account from SharePoint(central Admin / powershell).

- [central admin > Security > Configure Service Accounts](http://blog.morg.nl/2011/07/changing-the-identity-for-a-sharepoint-2010-application-pool-2/)
- After Changing please perform IIS on all servers.
- One Most important thing, before changing the account you should make sure new Account should have right permission on all related Database & config database.