# My site collection is not accessible using IE & Chrome , while I can access it uing Firefox

Tags: 2013, authentication, iis, browser-compatibility, server

I have a Team site collection at the root of my server, and can be accessed using the following  URL:-

> `http://servername`

now i can access it using firefox by entering the username/password and every thing will work find

while in IE 10 , I will be prompted to enter username/password forever, without being able to access the site. Baring in mind that I have added the `http://servername` to the local intranet site.

Also on google chrome I will get the following error

> The webpage at `http://servername/` might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web address. Error code:
>   ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS

Can anyone advice ?

**EDIT**
Here is the logs after i tried accessing the site from IE & Chrome

```
> 0/18/2014 23:18:59.08*    w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca42    Medium      ...vokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
> rpc)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
> rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> isOperationContextSet)).  8b25cc2d-ef4a-4d6f-9ff8-de4fd2eb07bc
> 10/18/2014 23:18:59.08    w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca3r    Monitorable Error encountered in background cache check
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The current user has insufficient
> permissions to perform this operation.     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<RunOnChannel>b__2d()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
> secureCode)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.RunOnChannel(CodeToRun
> codeToRun, Double operationTimeoutFactor)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.ReadApplicationSettings(Guid
> rawPartitionId)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.get_ServiceApplicationSettings()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.Tim...   8b25cc2d-ef4a-4d6f-9ff8-de4fd2eb07bc
> 10/18/2014 23:18:59.08*   w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca3r    Monitorable ...eToCheckForUpdates()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.TaxonomyCache.CheckForChanges(Boolean
> enforceUpdate)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.TaxonomyCache.<LoopForChanges>b__0().  8b25cc2d-ef4a-4d6f-9ff8-de4fd2eb07bc
> 10/18/2014 23:18:59.25    w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x2A50  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                  
>   uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)      10/18/2014 23:19:00.10
>   w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                           0x1D18  SharePoint Foundation
>   Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest:
> RemoteAddress:
> 'http://tgvstg01:32843/53d955de5e8e47dba7b0cde514c45009/MetadataWebService.svc'
> Channel:
> 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action:
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IMetadataWebServiceApplication/GetServiceSettings'
> MessageId:
> 'urn:uuid:fb220004-4c78-4bf4-b712-7915da3ef36d'   299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10    w3wp.exe (0x25A4)                      
>   0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation).
> Parent No   10/18/2014 23:19:00.10    w3wp.exe (0x25A4)                 
>   0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                     
>   e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress:
> 'http://tgvstg01.ad-tgroup.intra:32843/53d955de5e8e47dba7b0cde514c45009/MetadataWebService.svc'
> Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action:
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IMetadataWebServiceApplication/GetServiceSettings'
> MessageId:
> 'urn:uuid:fb220004-4c78-4bf4-b712-7915da3ef36d'   299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10    w3wp.exe (0x25A4)                      
>   0x2CF8  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   fgf2    High        Permission check failed for WFE web app user:
> permission check: '0000000000001000' term store: 'Managed Metadata
> Service'. 299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10
>   w3wp.exe (0x25A4)                           0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation
>   Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0
> nasq,0 e5mb,0 fgf2    299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.10   w3wp.exe (0x25A4)                      
>   0x2CF8  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation).
> Execution Time=1.17535887941065   299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10    w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca42    Medium      Exception returned from back end service.
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
> AccessDeniedEx:The current user has insufficient permissions to
> perform this operation. (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail,
> likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: AccessDeniedEx:The current user
> has insufficient permissions to perform this operation.    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetServiceSettings(Guid
> rawPartitionId)     at SyncInvokeGetServiceSettings(Object , Object[]
> , Object[] )     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
> instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.In... 299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10*   w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca42    Medium      ...vokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
> rpc)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
> rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> isOperationContextSet)).  299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10    w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca3r    Monitorable Error encountered in background cache check
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: The current user has insufficient
> permissions to perform this operation.     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<RunOnChannel>b__2d()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
> secureCode)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.RunOnChannel(CodeToRun
> codeToRun, Double operationTimeoutFactor)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.ReadApplicationSettings(Guid
> rawPartitionId)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.get_ServiceApplicationSettings()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.MetadataWebServiceApplicationProxy.Tim...   299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.10*   w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                     
>   ca3r    Monitorable ...eToCheckForUpdates()     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.TaxonomyCache.CheckForChanges(Boolean
> enforceUpdate)     at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Internal.TaxonomyCache.<LoopForChanges>b__0().  299dcfee-5208-499a-a508-b5f461254146
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2F5C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for ff172f26-efad-4010-bead-9cfaccde39c0). Parent
> No    fda5716e-111a-4b86-95a2-d0341cda9b4d 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83
>   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                       0x2F5C  SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job Rebalance
> crawl store partitions for
> ff172f26-efad-4010-bead-9cfaccde39c0  4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3cebdbafef07
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2380  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for 483d965f-4b65-4336-b7ee-5dfbc6ffe779). Parent
> No    dd2cbc6e-e84c-4265-b8ad-615df9254587 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83
>   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                       0x2380  SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job Rebalance
> crawl store partitions for
> 483d965f-4b65-4336-b7ee-5dfbc6ffe779  4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3acd45a1f477
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2174  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job
> job-immediate-alerts). Parent No  32e795c2-89ac-4f93-9cb1-21241f495687
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.83    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2174  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data     
>   xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job
> job-immediate-alerts  4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3367a87972dc 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.84   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x1A74  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for 95a90d97-e7d3-4b7d-9b26-b9959eef7a78). Parent
> No    935118cd-3dd5-4eeb-9d2c-e129dd769df8 10/18/2014 23:19:00.84
>   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                       0x1A74  SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job Rebalance
> crawl store partitions for
> 95a90d97-e7d3-4b7d-9b26-b9959eef7a78  4778c39c-1cb7-d003-e007-363c8e00f96c
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.86    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x13D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job User Profile
> Service Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob). Parent
> No    0f5b6ff8-d594-4120-8b69-c59dce648dc9 10/18/2014 23:19:00.86
>   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                       0x13D4  SharePoint Foundation
>   Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job User
> Profile Service
> Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob 4778c39c-1cb8-d003-e007-3010689a5adf
> 10/18/2014 23:19:00.86    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x13D4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job User Profile Service
> Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob). Execution
> Time=4.30480689584849 4778c39c-1cb8-d003-e007-3010689a5adf 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.86   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2174  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job
> job-immediate-alerts). Execution
> Time=26.5704160724338 4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3367a87972dc 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.92   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x1A74  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for 95a90d97-e7d3-4b7d-9b26-b9959eef7a78). Execution
> Time=85.2422584434614 4778c39c-1cb7-d003-e007-363c8e00f96c 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.92   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2380  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for 483d965f-4b65-4336-b7ee-5dfbc6ffe779). Execution
> Time=101.683524023305 4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3acd45a1f477 10/18/2014
> 23:19:00.94   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2350)                  
>   0x2F5C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                   
>   b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Rebalance crawl
> store partitions for ff172f26-efad-4010-bead-9cfaccde39c0). Execution
> Time=107.129607254553 4778c39c-2cb6-d003-e007-3cebdbafef07 10/18/2014
> 23:19:01.05   mssearch.exe (0x0848)                  
>   0x1858  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin       
>   cd11    Critical    Content Plugin can not be initialized - list of CSS
> addresses is not set.   10/18/2014 23:19:01.05    mssearch.exe (0x0848) 
>   0x1858  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin       
>   du0c    High        Failed to extract required parameter
> FastConnector:ContentDistributor, hr=0x80070002  [pluginconfig.cpp:81]
> search\native\gather\plugins\contentpi\pluginconfig.cpp     10/18/2014
> 23:19:01.11   w3wp.exe (0x1E7C)                      
>   0x1D18  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                     
>   e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress:
> 'http://tgvstg01:32843/53d955de5e8e47dba7b0cde514c45009/MetadataWebService.svc'
> Channel:
> 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.IMetadataWebServiceApplication' Action:
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IMetadataWebServiceApplication/GetServiceSettings'
> MessageId:
> 'urn:uuid:3823a0a3-021d-4aa5-bfd2-958a147445d2'   a50eb170-2828-4deb-ad30-b167c7183b13
```

Comment: Does this happen only for this team site or the whole web application? Are you accessing using the server name or an alias (intranet.company.com)? Have you looked into [DisableLoopbackCheck](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)?

Comment: i have another site collection of type enterprise wiki and it is working well on all the browsers...

Comment: Ok! Any hints from the [ULS logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx) or Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: @Choggo thanks for the reply, please find the edit for my original question after providing the related logs. can u adivce ?

Comment: Somewhat stumped. From that log information all I see related to an error is an issue regarding lack of access to the Managed Metadata service. Doesn't explain why it works for one browser and not others.

Comment: @Choggo so what other checks i can do ? it is very strange ..

Comment: As i checked the ULS logs and looks like issue with the MMS services, do one thing, add the App Pool account( site collection not working) into the administrator of the MMS services....check this http://sharepointandaspnet.blogspot.com/2014_03_01_archive.html

Comment: Ok i remove the whole MMS services but nothing solve this. please note that inside the SharePoint server i have two web applications. one of the web application is working on all browsers while the other is only working on Firefox,, can u advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a reason the authentication provider for my web application was changed from NTLM to kerberos. so i modify the Authntication provider to NTLM and now evertthing is working well.